# On my TEVO Tarantula, is there a way to test that its heater pins are working?

Tags: hotend, tevo-tarantula

I can no longer print anything because I get a E1 heating failed error on my TEVO Tarantula every time I try to heat the hotend. The bed heats just fine.

I've removed the heating element and thermistor from the hotend. The latter works fine, the temperature rises when I pinch it with my fingers. The element doesn't appear to have any broken connections.

I recently did some cable management and disconnected the element's wires from the board. After reattaching them, I was able to print a couple of things so the error has occurred since then. (They didn't turn out, btw, so maybe this was the beginning of a fault?)

The wires going to the board's E1 pins are secure. I've swapped them back and forth and reconnected them numerous times but no luck.

I know the most likely problem is a faulty element but before I buy a replacement is there a way to test the heating pins themselves? Some way to test the element separate from the printer?

Also, is there a way to have the element heat using the E0 pins? I've found tutorials on how to define the heater pins in Marlin but their code references don't appear in my configuration.h file.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but would assume you could put a multimeter (set to VDC) onto the two connections for the heater pins and check the voltage output during what would be the heating period. If there's voltage output, your heating element would be at fault.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get my hands on one (I've always wanted to own one). I've ordered replacement heating elements in the meantime so hopefully the original is simply shot. If not, I'll need to see about switching over to the other heater pins somehow.